# How Can I Freeze Enemy Ai Position In Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a FPS game in Unity, one of my player's abilities is to 'freeze' any enemy. I've tried this in 3 ways at the moment:

- using Rigidbody.Constraints
- Setting Target waypoint to the enemies current position.
- Resetting the path.

I use waypoints to make my enemies patrol the map.

Enemy Movement Code:

```
public class EnemyControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    NavMeshAgent agent;

    private Rigidbody rb;
    [SerializeField] Animator animator;

    bool isPatroling;

    public GameObject waypoints;

    int waypointIndex;
    Vector3 target;

    float xWanderRange;
    float zWanderRange;

    private float freezeDur = 1.5f;

    void Awake()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        animator.SetBool("isPatroling", true);

        waypointIndex = 0;
        UpdateDestination();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // checking if ai has reached destination or last waypoint.
        if (waypointIndex == waypoints.transform.childCount - 1 && agent.remainingDistance < 0.5f)
        {
            xWanderRange = Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f);
            zWanderRange = Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f);

            // checks that the distance is big enough to move enemy.
            if ((xWanderRange < -5.0f || xWanderRange > 5.0f) && (zWanderRange < -5.0f || zWanderRange > 5.0f))
            {
                Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(xWanderRange, 0, zWanderRange) + transform.position;

                NavMeshHit hit;
                if (NavMesh.SamplePosition(targetPosition, out hit, 1.0f, NavMesh.AllAreas))
                {
                    agent.destination = hit.position;
                }
            }
        }

        else if (agent.remainingDistance < 1.0f)
        {
           // Debug.Log("Reached destination");
            IterateWaypointIndex();
            UpdateDestination();
        }
    }

    void UpdateDestination()
    {
        target = waypoints.transform.GetChild(waypointIndex).position;
        agent.SetDestination(target);
    }

    void IterateWaypointIndex()
    {
        waypointIndex++;
        if (waypointIndex == waypoints.transform.childCount)
        {
            waypointIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    public void StopEnemy()
    {
        // make enemy destination their position.
        // agent.destination = transform.position;

        Debug.Log("freeze enemy");
        agent.ResetPath();

        animator.SetBool("isPatroling", false);

       // Invoke("UpdateDestination", freezeDur);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are they frozen for a finite amount of time, or forever?

Comment: i would like them to be frozen for a certain amount of time! around 1.5 - 2.0 seconds, i have the 'freezeDur' variable set to 1.5 so after 1.5seconds they should then continue going to the waypoints but they never seem to actually freeze, they just immediately change course of direction.

Comment: So, you'll need a to create a timer variable, and then use this in conjunction with @Chuck's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float timer = 0;
bool isFrozen = false;
void Update()
    {
    if(isFrozen){
        timer+= Time.deltaTime; //If isFrozen is true, ten add time to our timer

        if(timer > freezeDur){ // If the timer reaches freezeDur then unfreeze and reset the timer.
            isFrozen = false;
            timer = 0;

        }
    return; //finally return statement so you will not execute code below this loop so the agent wont be able to move untill he is unfrozen.
    }

        // checking if ai has reached destination or last waypoint.
        if (waypointIndex == waypoints.transform.childCount - 1 && agent.remainingDistance < 0.5f)
        {
            xWanderRange = Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f);
            zWanderRange = Random.Range(-10.0f, 10.0f);

            // checks that the distance is big enough to move enemy.
            if ((xWanderRange < -5.0f || xWanderRange > 5.0f) && (zWanderRange < -5.0f || zWanderRange > 5.0f))
            {
                Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(xWanderRange, 0, zWanderRange) + transform.position;

                NavMeshHit hit;
                if (NavMesh.SamplePosition(targetPosition, out hit, 1.0f, NavMesh.AllAreas))
                {
                    agent.destination = hit.position;
                }
            }
        }

        else if (agent.remainingDistance < 1.0f)
        {
           // Debug.Log("Reached destination");
            IterateWaypointIndex();
            UpdateDestination();
        }
    }

public void StopEnemy()
{
    // make enemy destination their position.
    // agent.destination = transform.position;

    Debug.Log("freeze enemy");
    //agent.ResetPath();

    animator.SetBool("isPatroling", false);
agent.destination = transform.position; //Set the destination to its current position to stop the NPC
isFrozen = true; //Set this to true to check in update (Needs refactoring dont use Update too much. Try coroutines?
   // Invoke("UpdateDestination", freezeDur);
}
```

See the `//Comments` above for explanation of my alterations. Good luck!

Comment: ah thank you so much! this worked <3 I understood it too - thank you so much.

Comment: Can you please mark it as Answered? :D Its my first answered question on here would be cool! You can mark it as the answer in the panel on the left next to my Answer! Thanks and have fun coding!

Comment: oh yes of course! i think i did it :))

Answer (score 0):

What went wrong with the methods you tried? I would just put an `isFrozen` bit in there and bail on the `Update` step if it is, like:

```
public class EnemyControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isFrozen = false;
    // stuff
    void Update()
    {
        if(isFrozen)
        {
            return;
        }
        // more Update stuff
    }

    // more stuff

    public void StopEnemy()
    {
        // make enemy destination their position.
        // agent.destination = transform.position;
        
        Debug.Log("freeze enemy");
        isFrozen = true;
       
        animator.SetBool("isPatroling", false);
        
        // Invoke("UpdateDestination", freezeDur);
    }
```